# MD5 password hash does not match after recovering from database

Tags: mysql, database, playframework, md5

I'm having a problem relative to the hash of my user's password in a MySQL database. During development I was using an in-memory database (with Playframework) and everything worked perfectly. But when going with a persistent database, the hash I recover does not match the hash I uploaded. I suppose therefore there's been some kind of encoding problem

Here are a few test I ran to find the problem

```
Salt at registration: hlsqjnv5vhplrgrsoa4g524b0q
Hash at registration: v�!�ȡuNB͞l�q�
User pwd hash: v!?uNB?lq
Salt at login: hlsqjnv5vhplrgrsoa4g524b0q
Input pwd hash: v�!�ȡuNB͞l�q�
```

Where the "User pwd hash" is the hash recovered from the database (we can see it does not match the hash at registration), "Input pwd hash" is the hash from the login form (which match the hash at registration).

Here is how I get the hash `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest((password+salt).getBytes("UTF-8"))`

And my database is utf8_general_ci

So everything seems to be in UTF-8 but I can't find the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you store the bate array as a String in the database? It is possible that some parts are lost during this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I've found a workaroud:

Just after creating the hash I use

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder

(new BASE64Encoder()).encode(encryptedPwd)
```

Which create a correct String that I can work with.